# openvpn part of the subnet is unavaliable

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a problem with my 'home' network... I've been pulling my hair out for the whole day now, and still cant find the solution. What is worse, I cant really pinpoint the source of the issue ;(

I have 3 subnets, configured on 3 different servers, in different locations:

**10.123.45.0/24 - location A**

```
$ ip route list
default via _PUBLIC_IP_ dev enp7s1  metric 2 
10.0.0.0/24 via 10.123.50.5 dev tun0 
10.123.45.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.123.45.1 
10.123.50.0/24 via 10.123.50.5 dev tun0 
10.123.50.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.123.50.6 
_PUBLIC_NETWORK_ dev enp7s1  proto kernel  scope link  src _PUBLICK_GW_  metric 2 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope host
```

---

```
$ sudo ifconfig tun0
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.123.50.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.123.50.5
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 58491  bytes 33386378 (31.8 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 68994  bytes 33653956 (32.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 28 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**10.123.50.0/24 - VPS - OpenVPN Server**

```
$ ip route list
default via _PUBLIC_IP_ dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 via 10.123.50.2 dev tun0 
10.123.45.0/24 via 10.123.50.2 dev tun0 
10.123.50.0/24 via 10.123.50.2 dev tun0 
10.123.50.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.123.50.1 
_PUBLIC_NETWORK_ dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src _PUBLIC_GW_
```

---

```
$ ifconfig tun0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:10.123.50.1  P-t-P:10.123.50.2  Mask:255.255.255.255                                           
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                               
      RX packets:307740 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                  
      TX packets:309435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100                                                                              
      RX bytes:20958272 (19.9 MiB)  TX bytes:66356464 (63.2 MiB)
```

**10.0.0.0/24 - location B**

```
$ ip route list
default via _PUBLIC_IP_ dev eth0 
10.0.0.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1 
10.123.45.0/24 via 10.123.50.9 dev tun0 
10.123.50.0/24 via 10.123.50.9 dev tun0 
10.123.50.9 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.123.50.10 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
_PUBLIC_NETWORK_ dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src _PUBLIC_GW_
```

---

```
$ ifconfig tun0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:10.123.50.10  P-t-P:10.123.50.9  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:37791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:37122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:7688111 (7.3 MiB)  TX bytes:2624779 (2.5 MiB)
```

**For some reason I cant reach hosts with IP > 10.0.0.10 from VPS - OpenVPN server and from location A**

```
$ ping 10.0.0.12
PING 10.0.0.12 (10.0.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 10.0.0.12 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

Ping from location A works for all hosts with IP <= 10.0.0.10. All hosts in 10.0.0.x work when pinged from server in location B.

```
$ ping 10.0.0.10
PING 10.0.0.10 (10.0.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=59.2 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=56.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=57.3 ms
--- 10.0.0.10 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 56.998/57.861/59.230/0.998 ms
```

And it works for all hosts when I ping from location B and VPS to A

```
$ ping 10.123.45.132
PING 10.123.45.132 (10.123.45.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.123.45.132: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=461 ms
64 bytes from 10.123.45.132: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=252 ms
64 bytes from 10.123.45.132: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=416 ms
...
```

This is what happens from tcpdump perspective on server in location B:

```
$ tcpdump -i br0 src 10.0.0.11 or dst 10.0.0.11 -vv
```

When I ping from the location B network 10.0.0.0/24 in this case pinging 10.0.0.11 from 10.0.0.1

```
nostromo > 10.0.0.11: ICMP echo request, id 19025, seq 1, length 64
21:52:56.910174 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16522, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
10.0.0.11 > nostromo: ICMP echo reply, id 19025, seq 1, length 64
21:52:57.908878 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2419, offset 0, flags [DF],  proto ICMP (1), length 84)
nostromo > 10.0.0.11: ICMP echo request, id 19025, seq 2, length 64
21:52:57.909110 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16523, offset 0, flags [none],  proto ICMP (1), length 84)
10.0.0.11 > nostromo: ICMP echo reply, id 19025, seq 2, length 64
21:52:58.907874 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2543, offset 0, flags [DF],  proto ICMP (1), length 84)
nostromo > 10.0.0.11: ICMP echo request, id 19025, seq 3, length 64
```

That was OK, I got the response

When I ping from location A 10.123.45.0/25 network in tcpdump i get:

```
10.123.45.2 > 10.0.0.11: ICMP echo request, id 8621, seq 17, length 64
21:52:14.645318 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 2554, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
10.123.45.2 > 10.0.0.11: ICMP echo request, id 8621, seq 18, length 64
21:52:15.643949 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 3048, offset 0, flags [DF],  proto ICMP (1), length 84)
10.123.45.2 > 10.0.0.11: ICMP echo request, id 8621, seq 19, length 64
```

There is no response, but why ???

Bridge configs:

location A:

```
bridge_br0="enp5s0"
config_br0="10.123.45.1/24"
brctl_br0="setfd 0 sethello 10 stp off"
```

location B:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp off       
bridge_waitport 0    
bridge_fd 0          
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

I count on your wisdom, please help.

Comment: What is the subnet of the virtual interfaces taking part in the OpenVPN?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Basically 10.123.50.0/24 is the VPN subnet, 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.123.45.0/24 are routed so that hosts on 10.0.0.0/24 can see hosts on 10.123.45.0/24 and the other way around. They also all see hosts on 10.123.50.0/24. As I mentioned the problem is that hosts from network 10.0.0.0/24 with IP > 10.0.0.10 are unavailable from remaining networks.